# SQL conditional statement cannot fetch first row data

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to do a search book whenever user types a ISBN or Title that matched the data in the database, it will show the details

In the SQL statement it state :

```
SELECT title,id,status 
FROM books 
WHERE isbn='$bookid' 
OR title='$bookid'
```

When I search using `title`,the data would fetch without a problem. However when i search using `isbn`, it says invalid ISBN or title,which i set below. The error happens ONLY the first row data, the other row worked well with isbn or title.

This is my php code:

```
//check book
if(!empty($_POST["bookid"])) 
    {
        $bookid = $_POST["bookid"];
        $query = "SELECT title,id,status FROM books WHERE isbn='$bookid' OR title='$bookid'";

        $server_name = "localhost";
        $db_username = "root";
        $db_password ="";
        $db_name = "adminpanel";

        $connection = mysqli_connect($server_name,$db_username,$db_password);
        $db_config = mysqli_select_db($connection, $db_name);

        $query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
        {
            foreach ($query_run as $row)
            {
                if($row['status']=='Available')
                {?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?></option>
                     <?php echo $row['title'];
                     echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',false);</script>";
                }
                else{?>
                    <option class ="others"><?php echo $row['title'];?> Book is UNAVAILABLE </option>
                    <?php
                    echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);</script>";
                }
            }
        }
        else{?>
                <option class ="others"> Invalid ISBN Number or Title </option>
            <?php
            echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);</script>";

        }
    }
```

[image: interface]

The table data: The first row with id-10

[image: here]

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize your query. Please add the compiled query and the data the first row has.

Comment: Try hard coding the ISBN number that is failing to help isolate the problem.

Comment: Please show su the COMPLETE Error message, not a summary

Comment: If it works for other rows, the error message may be right. Double check ISBN.